# DC-DC Boost converter IC with external MOSFET?

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I've got a shitty (low pixie production capabilities) step-up LED driver ([FAN5331](https://store.comet.bg/download-file.php?id=7984)) and I was wondering if I can make it more powerful by adding an external MOSFET to the switching pin of the thing. [image]
Would this design work well enough? Ignore the coil and resistor divider values, they have been used in a previous design. I'm trying to get 12V ~700mA from a USB port and I don't have a better idea by now. I can also use an ATTINY25 to do the job, it can switch close to 250KHz but it's not quite the 1.6MHz this little chip promises, which can be more easily filtered.

Comment: In theory yes. But why not get yourself a better suitee regulator or if you must have external FET - a controller?

Comment: What makes you think you can get 10W from the USB port ? Also no soft start.

Comment: 10W from a USB *charger* seems reasonable (although at that point, why not just buy a 12V DC adapter?), but 10W from a regular USB port (e.g. on a laptop) isn't going to work without properly negotiating power requirements with the host.

Comment: @Tony Stewart the power bank I've got laying around can push out 3.2A at 5V (well, almost, it drops to 4.6V but still within the USB standard) ,Apple's iPad charger can supply 2.1A. What's the problem with getting 10W from a USB port?

Comment: @Polynomial I'm trying to make a portable speaker amplifier so I need to work with USB power banks (I don't trust myself enough for using LiPo's to get the 12V without something catching on fire). And since I've seen some good powerful power banks around I think I can squeeze 10W out of them for a couple of hours of playback.

Comment: Design your amp to run on 15V, and put three power banks in series. Use bypass Schottky diodes to protect the power bank outputs. Not in series. Install the diode directly across the output so that it is reverse biased in normal operation. When one bank shuts down, it will feel 10V of reverse voltage from the other two banks and the load. Which may blow it up unless you put in the Schottky.

Comment: @mkeith I think that's what I'm going to do, thank you! And ignore the comment on your answer, apparently too much beer can mess with your ability to read things properly :). Have a great weekend!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I very much doubt that this will work at all. If you look at the block diagram for the FAN5331, you will see that it senses the current flowing to GND through SW. It uses this current as an input to the feedback loop which maintains regulation. If this current is not proportional to inductor current, I think the output regulation will totally fail.

Also, while I did not scrutinize your schematic carefully, you would certainly need a resistor in series with the base of Q8. Otherwise you are going to blow up Q8 by putting 5V across the emitter-base junction. Whenever you use a BJT as a switch, you will need a resistor in series with the base to limit base current.

Comment: Oh, I don't know what that S in a circle means so I thought it uses current sensing just for over-current protection.
Thanks for the quick response!
edit: What does that S mean tho, I'm dying of curiosity (if it's not too much to ask) :D